# MWC: how to rerender on URL change

Tags: javascript, meteor, polymer, web-component

Heyo everyone,

**story time - skip if you don't care**

I'm just starting out with Meteor + Polymer using [Synthesis](https://atmospherejs.com/mwc/synthesis) by @aruntk and I'm very happy about the results and greatful for the time he's invested in this project. There's one issue I'm having though.

I've previously only changed a iron-pages object to change the content of my view. Putting that in a FlowRouter like `FlowRouter.route("/", action: {ironpages.select("home");});` works just fine. However, my site is getting more complex and I want to rerender a whole section now. I'm being told to do it reactively which is (to my poor understanding) the preferred way of building Apps here.

**tl;dr - skip to here if you don't care about stories**

So what I did is just putting `mwcLayout.render("test-layout",{"main":"yas-manual-page"});` in my Router action. However, I have to reload to make the changes visible which is not what I want.

- the router action is being called when changing the URL
- the `mwcLayout.render()` call works if I reload the page once in the initial building of the site
- calling `mwcLayout.render()` again at a later point does not do anything

I've read up on the topic and people say it's a problem with single-page apps and not building it reactively and whatnot, but I have no idea how this is not reactive. It's reacting to the URL change.

Please, if you have a minute, share some insight with me, I'm really stuck. :slight_smile:

Have a wonderful day y'all!

---

disclaimer: it's a repost form the Meteor forums which suggests coming here instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is added as a feature of mwc layout to prevent multiple re rendering during each route change. Workarounds here are to create another mwc layout or to set third argument `forceRender`. From the mwc:layout docs

**forceRender**

In mwc:layout we dont re render the layout unless the new layout is not equal to the current layout or `forceRender` argument is set. This is to prevent unwanted rerendering while changing routes(even if you change a param/queryparam the route gets rerun so does the render function written inside FlowRouter action). `forceRender` comes in handy when you have to change the rendering while keeping the current layout.

```
...
<mwc-layout id="demo-landing">
      <div region="header"></div>
      <div region="main"></div>
</mwc-layout>
...
```

imports/startup/client/router.js

```
...
  action:function(params,queryParams){
    mwcLayout.render("demo-landing",{"main":"test-layout1","header":"test-header"});
  }
...
```

Now if you try

```
mwcLayout.render("demo-landing",{"main":"test-layout2","header":"test-header"});
```

from console it wont work since layout is not changed and `forceRender` is not set.

This works->

```
mwcLayout.render("demo-landing",{"main":"test-layout","header":"test-header"},true);
```